# Manipulate api to show data from a clicked element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So, im learning React and am building an app that uses the Marvel api to display heroes's info. Right now I have a page displaying image and name of all heroes. Id like to know how can I manipulate the api so that when clicking the pic of a hero it leads me to a page containing more details of them (description, list of series, etc) contained in the API. I probably have to use states for that but i dont really know how to approach this scenario. Here's the code of what I got:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import "../App.css";
import Heroes from './Heroes';

const FetchApi = () =>{

 const apikey = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
 const public_key = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
 const md = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
 const apiURL=`https://gateway.marvel.com:443/v1/public/charactersts=1&apikey=${public_key}&hash=${md}`

 const [heroes, setHeroes] = useState([])
 

  useEffect (()=>{
      getData();
  
},[])

      const getData = async()=>{
      const data = await fetch(apiURL)
      const response = await data.json()
      setHeroes(response.data.results)
      console.log(response.data.results)
  }

  return(

      <div className='App'>
  
          <input type='text' className='search-bar'/>
         <button className='search-button'>Search</button> 
            <div>
          {heroes.map(hero =>(
           <Heroes
           image = {hero.thumbnail.path+'.jpg'}
           title ={hero.name}

          />
       ))}
          </div>  
       
      </div>
  )
}
export default FetchApi;
```

Answer (score 1):

Well if you want to show another page regarding hero details you can pass the name of hero through route ex: http://marvelheros/TonyStark you can redirect programatically.
https://dev.to/projectescape/programmatic-navigation-in-react-3p1l

another approach is you can use a pop-up to display hero details

Answer (score 1):

First you need to create onClick event on Heros mapped component then pass it on history,push and create routes in app.js, then get the passed path as match.params. .....

```
 <div>{heroes.map(hero =>(
           <Heroes onClick={() => onHeroClick(hero)}
           image = {hero.thumbnail.path+'.jpg'}
           title ={hero.name}

          />
       ))}
          </div> 




const onHeroClick = (hero) => {    
//  hero must have a unique id/name here which u can pass to the link
history.push('/heros/' + hero.name)}
```

on app.js

```
<Route path={'/hero/:heroname} />
```

on New Component where u show hero details:

```
const Component2 = ({match}) => {

match.params.heroname = a unique id/name u sent withhistory.push('/heros/' + hero.name)
```

Comment: Cool idea but im in doubt about the onClick in <Heroes/> how would that work?

Comment: if u click on heroes it will navigate you to dynamic route with history.push. you have to import history from react-router-dom

Answer (score 0):

```
"Id like to know how can I manipulate the api ..."
```

I think you need to check the Marvel API Docs for that.

From my experience, APIs usually comes with a certain pattern. Say for example we have an API for books in a library:

1. Hitting `/books` URL means that you will get all the books in the library. The result will definitely be an `array of objects`. Just like what you have with the heroes.
2. Hitting `/books/43` URL means that you will get the detail of a certain book. Here, it is with book ID equals 43. The result should be an object with all the information for that certain book. This is what you are searching for.

I haven't use nor read the Marvel API, but I believe it should be there in the documentation.

To implement it in your React App, you can definitely use the example from [Sushilzzz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62992195/9844546).